# Why does throwing an unchecked exception removes the "missing return statement" error

Tags: java, exception, return, throw, unchecked-exception

I am very new at programming and the problem thus might seem very silly. The below mentioned method has a return type as an int array. When we don't throw any unchecked exception it throws an error which I understand. But why does including an unchecked exception removes that error? It still does not have any return statement, isn't it correct?

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                    return new int[] { i, j };
                }
            }
        }
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
    }
```

Comment: The method does _terminate_, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases where your program never reaches the inner return statement. E.g. if `nums` has a length of 0 or if `nums[j] == target - nums[i]` is never true. For these cases the method needs either return something or it can throw an exception. It is your decision what is the correct behaviour for your use case. If nothing is defined for such cases and your IDE would let you get through with it you would have broken code. If you throw an exception instead of doing nothing your IDE says its fine because your code is correct on a technical level.

Comment: Ok, I get it. So, even if a method has a return type, we can always throw an exception without actually returning the value. Which might be technically correct but not logically. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @the_novice in a method for each point where you decide to exit the method (and the points where it ends) you can either throw an exception or return something (in case where the method is defined to return nothing you can exit it with a plain `return;` ).

Comment: @the_novice can you upvote and accept the answer if your question is answered, please?

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual requirement for there to be a return statement in a method with a non-void return type. For example:

```
int huh() {
  while (true) {}
}
```

is [legal](https://ideone.com/Qcnwz8).

The requirement is that the method can't complete *normally* ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)):

> **If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).**

Normal completion is basically when execution "falls off the bottom" of the method, that is, reaches the end of the method without encountering a return or throw statement.

So, if you put a throw statement at the end of your method, execution can't reach the end of the method, so it's legal.

In the case of the `huh()` example above, the while loop doesn't complete normally, so execution cannot reach the end of the method, so you don't need a return or throw there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This really helps.

Answer (score 1):

The exception forcibly punts you from the called method. The calling method is then forced to catch the exception and continue computation without access to the return value of the called method.

If the exception is unavoidable / unconditional, then a return statement that follows is never necessary or useful.